Userform delete function VBA run-time error '94'
I am working on a VBA userform so you can enter/delete data on a table, I had no issues with the adding data code, but when it came to deleting the data I'm running into error 94. I would really appreciate some insight on what's going on, thank you!
For Reference, the table is named 'Table2'
The worksheet is named 'VendorList'
The form is named 'UserForm1'
The button is named 'cmdDelete'
The line of code that's throwing the error is:
mySt = lstDisplay.Value

Attached below is the code for the sub.
Private Sub UserForm1_Initialize()

lstDisplay.List = Sheets("VendorList").ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Value

End Sub

Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()
    Dim myTab As ListObject
    Dim mySt As String, fndmySt As Range

    If lstDisplay.ListIndex <> -1 Then
            If Me.lstDisplay.ListIndex > -1 Then
                     mySt = ""
                If mySt = "" Then
                        mySt = lstDisplay.Value
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox "Please select a row!", vbExclamation
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Set myTab = Sheets("VendorList").ListObjects(1)
    With myTab.ListColumns(1).Range
        Set fndmySt = .Find(What:=mySt, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    End With
            If Not fndmySt Is Nothing Then
                myTab.ListRows(fndmySt.Row - myTab.HeaderRowRange.Row).Range.Delete
            End If
        lstDisplay.List = myTab.DataBodyRange.Value
    End If
End Sub


Which line is causing the error?

Does this doc help? Try stepping through your code and see which line throws the error.

mySt = lstDisplay.Value is throwing the error - my apologies, I accidently didn't include it in the OP

Error 94 means Invalid use of Null. So don't assign a Null to a String variable.
